# How to rearrange items in a list view according to their priority?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working on a tasks app, in which I am trying to setup a listview. Now, I am a little bit of a beginner, so I am wanting to ask you how I can implement what I'm thinking as code...

The user enters tasks, and also tells me the priority and the time taken by the respective tasks. Now, once the user enters all the data, I want to write code that rearranges all that data in the order of decreasing priority and increasing time. For example, a task that has high priority but takes less time must be listed at the first position, and so on... I tried doing stuff with indexes of the items of the list, but it didnt work out too well. Is there any way to go about this? thanks.

Comment: If you sort the data set of the list, then the list should/would be updated. What have you tried, what is the code? What was the behavior you have seen?

Comment: I tried using tons of if-else statements... Like, if (priorityhigh) and then its combinations... But looking at all possible combinations myself is not possible ig, since there are around 3! of em

Comment: This is a programming site, so, we would like to be able to see your code to help. What have you tired? Comparing using Comparator, and sorting the data set seems enough

Comment: @Bonatti yeah man, I understand. I was able to do it. I didn't use the priority queue, the comparator worked just fine. I created a custom one tho... I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a custom comparator worked just fine. I came up with a simple algorithm , which involved assigning simple integers like 10, 9 and 8 to the priorities high, medium and low respectively, and 1 , 2 and 3 to the time. The comparator just subtracts the time from priority and uses that as a comparison parameter. Works great. This is the code for the comparator class :

```
package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class TaskComparator implements Comparator<SubtaskPartTwo> {

    public int compare(SubtaskPartTwo s1, SubtaskPartTwo s2){

        int a = s1.getPri() - s1.getTime();
        int b = s2.getPri() - s2.getTime();
        int x = s1.getPri();
        int y = s2.getPri();

        if (b == a){

            return y-x;

        }
        else {
            return b-a;
        }

    }
}
```

Using the following line of code in the List Adapter class made it work :

```
// THIS IS WHERE I USE SORT
        Collections.sort(values, new TaskComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write something like that. Look into `PriorityQueue`, it does exactly just that:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

The class implements the `Iterator` interface, so you will have access to specific elements if you don't just need the one of highest importance in the list.

If you need a more complex priority comparison you can implement a `Comparator` with a custom `compare` method:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

This should provide all the functionality you need.

Comment: Right. I think I'm going to try Priority queue , since it pretty much matches with what I want

Answer (score 1):

Come up with a formula by which sorting will be performed, *e.g.*:

```
(((p / 2) * 100) * p)  + ((t / 2) * 100) * t)
```

- `p` - priority
- `t` - time

In the example priority and time have equal weight.

Comment: Not sure I am able to understand the formula properly..., sorry.